# Issues in generating Mongo query using Morphia with nested $and and $or criteria

Tags: java, mongodb-query, morphia

Need to construct a Mongo query dynamically based on expression pattern. But noticed that Morphia query built is producing wrong results even with hardcoded criteria

Created a BasicDAO with morphia-1.3.2.jar.
Created a Unit test with System.out.println constructing a query with the criteria expected.

```
System.out.println("Test Query" + 


    ((CriteriaContainerImpl) query1.and(
                                    query1.or(
                                                 query1.criteria("_id").equal("234"), query1.criteria("_id").equal("456")
                                              ),
                                    query1.and(
                                                query1.or(
                                                            query1.criteria("_id").equal("789"), query1.criteria("_id").equal("666")
                                                           ),
                                                query1.criteria("_id").equal("459")
                                                )
                                        )
                            )
                        .getQuery().toString());
```

Actual Result:

```
{ query: { "_id" : "459", "$or" : [{ "_id" : "789" }, { "_id" : "666" }] }  }
```

This is the result produced as part of above print statement.

Expected Result:

```
{query: 
{ "$and":[
            { "$or" : [{ "_id" : "234" }, { "_id" : "456" }] } ,
            {"$and":[
                { "$or" : [{ "_id" : "789" }, { "_id" : "666" }] },
                {"_id":459}
                    ]
            }     ] }}
```

Comment: relates to https://github.com/MorphiaOrg/morphia/issues/1278

Answer (score 0):

upgrading to morphia 1.5.0 or above is resolving this issue. Got the solution from Morphia forum.
https://github.com/MorphiaOrg/morphia/issues/1278